# Redirect all messages to log file from inside script except some print command output on console as well as screen

Tags: bash, stdout

I want to write all stdout of script to a log file by default but want to display some messages on the console as well. Below is the sample code I tried.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG='output.txt'
exec 3>&1
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>>$LOG
echo "This should be written to log"
echo "This should be written to both screen as well as log"|tee -a >&3
```

This writes `This should be written to log` to the log file, which is good.

It writes `This should be written to both screen as well as log` only on the console, but I want it to be written to both console and log.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a filename on your tee command. Try it like this:

```
echo "This should be written to both screen as well as log"|tee -a $LOG >&3
```